# Pandas: Combine and average data in a column based on length of month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe which consists of departments, year, the month of invoice, the invoice date and the value.

I have offset the Invoice dates by business days and now what I am trying to achieve is to combine all the months that have the same number of working days (so the 'count' of each month by year) and average the value for each day.

The data I have is as follows:

```
                    Department  Year      Month      Invoice Date   Value
0                Sales          2019      March       2019-03-25   1000.00
1                Sales          2019      March       2019-03-26   2000.00
2                Sales          2019      March       2019-03-27   3000.00
3                Sales          2019      March       2019-03-28   4000.00
4                Sales          2019      March       2019-03-29   5000.00
...                        ...   ...        ...              ...       ...
2435            Specialist      2020     August       2020-08-27   6000.00
2436            Specialist      2020     August       2020-08-28   7000.00
2437            Specialist      2020  September       2020-09-01   8000.00
2438            Specialist      2020  September       2020-09-02   9000.00
2439            Specialist      2020  September       2020-09-07   1000.00
```

The count of each month is as follows:

```
Year  Month
2019  April        21
      August       21
      December     20
      July         23
      June         20
      March         5
      May          21
      November     21
      October      23
      September    21
2020  April        21
      August       20
      February     20
      January      22
      July         23
      June         22
      March        22
      May          19
      September     5
```

My hope is that using this count I could aggregate the data from the original df and average for example April, August, May, November, September (2019) along with April (2020) as they all have 21 working days in the month.

Producing one dataframe with each day of the month an average of the months combined for each # of days.

I hope that makes sense.

Note: Please ignore the 5 days length, just incomplete data for those months...

Thank you

EDIT: I just realised that the days wont line up for each month so my plan is to aggregate it based on whether its the first business day of the month, then the second the third etc regardless of the actual date.
ALSO (SORRY): I was hoping it could be by department!

```
        Department   Month Length  Day Number  Average Value
    0   Sales           21              1            20000
    1   Sales           21              2            5541
    2   Sales           21              3            87485
    3   Sales           21              4            1863
    4   Sales           21              5            48687
    5   Sales           21              6            486996
    6   Sales           21              7            892
    7   Sales           21              8            985
    8   Sales           21              9            14169
    9   Sales           21             10            20000
   10   Sales           21             11            5541
   11   Sales           21             12            87485
   12   Sales           21             13            1863
   13   Sales           21             14            48687
   14   Sales           21             15            486996
   15   Sales           21             16            892
   16   Sales           21             17            985
   17   Sales           21             18            14169
   ......
```

So to explain it a bit better lets take sales, and all the months which have 21 days in them, for each day in those 21 day months I am hoping to get the average of the value and get a table that looks like above.

So 'day 1' is an average of all 'day 1s' in the 21 day months (as seen in the count df)! This is to allow me to then plot a line chart profile to show average revenue value on each given day in a 21 day month. I hope this is a bit of a better explanation, apologies.

Comment: Are you looking for a two dimensional data concept like Month x Days averaged through the years? Meaning you would have 12 months * 31 days averages?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure whether I understand your question. Maybe you could add an expected df to your question?

In the mean time would this point you in the direction you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import randint
from calendar import month_name


df = pd.DataFrame({'years': [randint(1998, 2020) for x in range(10000)],
                   'months': [month_name[randint(1, 12)] for x in range(10000)],
                   'days':  [randint(1, 30) for x in range(10000)],
                   'revenue': [randint(0, 1000) for x in range(10000)]}
                  )

print(df.groupby(['months', 'days'])['revenue'].mean())
```

Output is:

```
months     days
April      1       475.529412
           2       542.870968
           3       296.045455
           4       392.416667
           5       475.571429
   
September  26      516.888889
           27      539.583333
           28      513.500000
           29      480.724138
           30      456.500000
Name: revenue, Length: 360, dtype: float64
```

Comment: added a better explanation!

Comment: Sorry, but I am still not sure to understand what you need. You can pipe group operations. Would something like grouping first on year and month basis and then finally on the days help? `print(df.groupby(['years', 'months', 'days'])['revenue'].mean().groupby('days').mean())`

Comment: Sorry!! I will go and think about how to better explain this! thank you anyway!